# JSON.NET Object Properties

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to tackle a case like this?

I am receiving very "flat" json data such as

```
 {"Color":"Red", "Number":"7", "Name":"Bob"}
```

however in .NET I have two classes like this:

```
 Class Person
  { 
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="Name")]
    public personName {get;set;}

    [//HOW DO I DO THIS HERE???]
    public ColorInfo favoriteColor {get;set;}
  }

 Class ColorInfo
 {
   public String color {get;set;}
 }
```

So as you can see, I am getting data that doesn't match any part of my object. To tackle basic things, I just do JsonProperty and that will map one to the other (so Name in json maps to personName perfectly). However what about a case where my class has a property of type ColorInfo (a custom class) and THAT class has a property called color?

I need to somehow travel into the color class and assign that color property to the on in json.

Does anyone have thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CustomCreationConverter`, the code is simpler:

```
public class PersonConverter : JsonCreationConverter<Person>
{
    protected override Person Create(Type objectType, JObject jObject)
    {
        if (FieldExists("favoriteColor ", jObject))
        {
            return new Person() { favoriteColor = new ColorInfo() { Color = "Red" };
        }
    }

    private bool FieldExists(string fieldName, JObject jObject)
    {
        return jObject[fieldName] != null;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( personInstance);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>( serializedObject , new PersonConverter());
```

Comment: Wait i'm confused - ColorInfo is not actually a subclass of Person, sorry. I can't return a new ColorInfo in this way. Also is this really the way to do it? I'm having a tough time understanding how this would take a "favoriteColor" string (red, for example) and assigning the ColorInfo's property to the ColorInfo, then assigning ColorInfo to Person. If you could shed a little more light I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks will try - also JsonCreationConverter is a class I'd have to make myself right? It's not native to json.net?

Comment: Thank you this did it :) Truly appreciate your assistance.